# How to view unicode khmer on android?

Tags: android

public class WebKhmer2Activity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);

       String source = "អ្នកជាមនុស្ស​ មិនមែនសត្វ";
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null",source,"text/html","UTF-8",null);
```

}
}//output just like box it should be អ្នកជាមនុស្ស មិនមែនសត្វ

Answer (score 0):

It's getting easier now, but still not out of the box.  There is a group on facebook that has a lot of documentation (because the hacks for Khmer Unicode vary depending on your software and hardware).  I would recommend joining the facebook group [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/caug.talk/). And then check out the files they have for documentation on various methods for getting Khmer Unicode to work on Android [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/caug.talk/files/).